# Firebase documentation: where is the documentation for FirebaseAuth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/ and I see this code snippets:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

I believe that the "FirebaseAuth" class is not part of the FirebaseUI library. I believe it is a part of the firebase SDK.

So I go to the reference for the firebase SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/package-summary). But I cannot find this class anywhere, or the method .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).

Can someone point me to the documentation for FirebaseAuth? I guess the answer I am looking for would be a URL, along with a conceptual explanation of how this code is organized.

Comment: On the top of the page, there are tabs: `Overview`, `Guides`, `Reference` and `Samples`.  **Guides** and **Samples** are organized by Feature whereas **Reference** is organized by Platform/Language.  **Guides** are sub-organized by platform/language.  Guides are good for step-by-step instructions and Reference is good for API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth

I don't see where else you would rather find this.